# Discounts for multiple events in a cart

Tags: cividiscount

I don't know too much about the internals of CiviDiscount but we have a scenario where we would like to offer a discount when you have multiple events in your cart (4 for the price of 3, 20% off when you book three or more events, etc.)

I was wondering whether CiviDiscount would be a good basis for this. I was (naively?) thinking that there might be a hook in the CiviDiscount extension that you could use for this kind of use case.

Does it make sense to think about adding such a hook to the cividiscount framework?

Or maybe a more sensible approach is to use hook_civicrm_buildAmount.

Any thoughts people have on the best way to go about this appreciated.